# How do I change the bg color of chmod 777 directories in tcsh?

Tags: shell, color, slackware, command-line-interface

On my MacBook Pro, I have iTerm and use the (black background) Pastel color set. World writable directories show up with a yellow background behind grey text. This I can live with, since the grey is dark enough to still be visible when surrounded by the muted yellow color.

But when I connect to my company's Slackware servers (via ssh and tcsh as my shell on the remote side), 777 directories show up as solid blocks of light green, as both bg and text color are identical (or close enough to make the text impossible to read).

How do I change the color used for the backgrounds of world-readable (777) directories?

Thanks!

-Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that this is output from ls, rather than tab-completion of shells?  (I know at least one shell which can colourise shell tab-completions but you don't say, so I'll assume ls).

Use `$LS_COLORS`, often initialised via the dircolors(1) command. `dircolors -p` to see the defaults, take the output from the two systems and diff.

Drop the desired config into `~/.dircolors` and then:

```
set d=$HOME/.dircolors
if ( -r $d ) eval `dircolors -c $d`
```

[modified from the info docs for dircolors invocation, in the coreutils package]

Comment: To reproduce the gray on yellow, you'll probably want `ow=103;30;01`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing both sticky-world-write and just regular sticky (its only purpose is world-write, right? usually at least) to the same value, namely ...37;44 which is white on a blue background. Much less annoying than the typical black on yellow which always calls for your attention and there is nothing suspicious going on.

Much less annoyed now (I tended and still tend to remove the o-w from everything I can find just so it doesn't show up that way with ls ;-). At least now if it is *supposed* to be world writeable, I can give it sticky as well, and then it will be fine.

`dircolors -c .dircolors` results in a `setenv LS_COLORS '...'` which is for c-shell. For bourne-shell (bash), you have to use `dircolors -b`.

Answer (score 2):

**Easy way**

Just put

> LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=103;30;01"

at end of your .bashrc and reload (source ~/.bashrc) or logout and login.